# Password-Sync (browser) with AUTH TLS support?

Tags: security, browser, sync, passwords, password-management

I'm looking for a **addon/plugin or standalone software-solution** to sync passwords with my own servers by using AUTH TLS. In fact, I do not trust projects like Firefox-Sync or LASTPASS and my superior prohibits them too.

- The old XMARKS-Team provided a addon for Firefox called
  "**XMARKS-Bios**"
  ([http://blog.xmarks.com/2009/07/byos-....](http://blog.xmarks.com/2009/07/byos-edition-10-now-available_7004.html)) but it it's not compatible with newer
  versions of Firefox and apropos of
  nothing XMARKS has been closed
  several months before :-(

Any good and clear technical sources for info are greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Firefox Sync and Xmarks have **built-in support** for synchronizing with your own server instead of the hosted service (which is why the "BYOS" extension is not developed anymore).

- [Firefox Sync with your own server](http://thias.marmotte.net/2010/10/firefox-sync-with-your-own-server/)
- *LifeHacker* – [How to Continue Syncing Bookmarks with Xmarks on Your Own Server](http://lifehacker.com/5651152/how-to-continue-syncing-bookmarks-with-xmarks-on-your-own-server)